# NullReferenceException when attempting to retrieve a connection string

Tags: c#

When I try

```
var con = new SqlConnection(
                  ConfigurationManager
                  .ConnectionStrings["RegConnectionString"]
                  .ConnectionString);
```

I get the following error:

> Error message-null reference exception
>   object reference not set to an instance of an object

What is going wrong?

Comment: You connection string is probably not defined in web.config or is named something else.

Comment: well looks like there is no connection string named `RegConnectionString` defined in your config file?

Comment: (assuming this is what you want to know, since your 'question' doesn't have an actual question, just a line of code and an exception message, I think that) The ConfigurationManager doesn't seem to have found your connection string.

Comment: google: "**connection string webconfig**" - you'll surely find the answer!

Comment: Whatever happened to requiring that a question actually be asked?

Comment: @BobHorn: Good point.  But then, that's why anyone can [edit] to improve.

Answer (score 3):

Check for a mis-spelled or missing Configuration setting.

99.99999% of the time this error happens on this line of code, the issue is that the SqlConnecton setting in the Web.Config (or app.config) is either missing or mis-spelled.

(Actually, in my experience it's 100% of the time, but you never know.  There are exceptions to darn near everything.)

From [here](http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/store-connection-string-in-web-config):

> Connection string in .NET 3.5 (and above) config file
>
> Do not use appsettings in web.config. Instead use the
>   connectionStrings section in web.config.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="myConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

> use the ConfigurationSettings class. string connStr =

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

So YOUR web.config should contain

```
<add name="RegConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
```

Of course, you'll need to replace the server name, database name, username, password, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <!-- snip -->
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="RegConnectionString"
             connectionString="Put your connex string here drrr" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: This is one of those times when the **blink** tag would be very beneficial.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably missing the `RegConnectionString` connection string in your web.config.

Here's an example. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233.aspx) for more information.

```
<configuration>
<!-- Other configuration settings -->
 <connectionStrings>    
  <add name="RegConnectionString" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
       connectionString="server=.;database=NorthWind;Integrated Security=SSPI" />    
 </connectionStrings>    
<!-- Other configuration settings -->
</configuration>
```